# Unexpected printouts interfere with tqdm progress bar in PyTorch training run

Tags: python, pytorch, tqdm

I am trying to understand how the progress bar using `tqdm` works exactly. I have some code that looks as follows:

```
import torch
import torchvision
print(f"torch version: {torch.__version__}")
print(f"torchvision version: {torchvision.__version__}")

load_data()
manual_transforms = transforms.Compose([])
train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names = data_setup.create_dataloaders()

# them within the main function I have placed the train function that exists in the `engine.py` file
def main():

      results = engine.train(model=model,
        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
        test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss_fn=loss_fn,
        epochs=5,
        device=device)
```

and the `engine.train()` function includes the following code `for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):` then, the training for each batch takes place to visualize the progress of the training. Each time the tqdm runs for each step it prints also the following statements:

```
print(f"torch version: {torch.__version__}")
print(f"torchvision version: {torchvision.__version__}")
```

So finally, my question is why this is happening. How does the main function have access to these global statements and how can avoid printing everything in each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are noticing has actually nothing to do with `tqdm`, but rather with the inner workings of PyTorch (in particular, the `DataLoader`'s `num_workers` attribute) and Python's underlying `multiprocessing` framework. Here is a minimum working example that should reproduce your problem:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm
print("torch version:", torch.__version__)

class DummyData(Dataset):
    def __len__(self): return 256
    def __getitem__(self, i): return i

def main():
    for batch in tqdm(DataLoader(DummyData(), batch_size=16, num_workers=4)):
        pass  # Do something
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Enforce "spawn" method (e.g. on Linux) for subprocess creation to
    # reproduce problem (suppress error for reruns in same interpreter)
    with suppress(RuntimeError): set_start_method("spawn")
    main()
```

If you run this piece of code, you should see your PyTorch version number be printed exactly 4 times, messing up your `tqdm` progress bar. It is not a coincidence that this number is the same as `num_workers` (which you can easily check by changing this number).

What happens is the following:

- If `num_workers` is > 0, then subprocesses are launched for the workers.
- On Windows and macOS, these subprocesses are launched with the "spawn" method by default (on Linux, one can enforce this method to reproduce your observation, which I have done with `set_start_method()`).
- The "spawn" method will launch your main script once for each subprocess, executing all the lines that are not guarded by an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. This includes your `print()` calls on top of the script.

The behavior is documented [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#platform-specific-behaviors), along with potential mitigations. The one that would work for you, I guess, is:

> Wrap most of you main script’s code within `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, to make sure it doesn’t run again

So, either

1. move the `print()` calls to the beginning of your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block,
2. move the `print()` calls to the beginning of your `main()` function, or
3. remove the `print()` calls.

Alternatively, but this is probably not what you want, you can set `num_workers=0`, which will disable the underlying use of `multiprocessing` altogether (but in this way you will also lose the benefits of parallelization). Note that you should probably also move other function calls (such as `load_data()`) into the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or into the `main()` function to avoid multiple unintended executions.

Comment: Oh, amazing answer. That makes sense, I overlooked that worker case that you can find in dataloader indeed. I thought that the multiprocessing was embedded in tqdm or sth like that. I will try to have a better look at the multiprocessing framework. If you have any good material feel free to recommend it.

Comment: Hi @JoseRamon, I am glad I could help. Regarding the multiprocessing framework: I don't think it will be of much use to dig deeper there. I think the most important thing in terms of multiprocessing and PyTorch is the documentation that I linked above (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#platform-specific-behaviors). I would suggest: (1) read it (and maybe the surrounding sections), (2) try to understand the implications regarding your code (such as the behavior you observed and that led to your question), (3) try to adjust your code accordingly (such as the suggestions from my answer).